# Handle exceptions and errors in date parsing in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with big databases that have some dates. Currently, the dates are strings in this format `dd/mm/YYYY` so I use `pd.to_datetime()`. It works for almost every table but I have a few there is not working because some of the dates are wrong. For example, instead of '1999' it is '0199'. Because of this, the output was `"out of bounds nanosecond timestamp"`

Since the errors don't follow a pattern and I don't want to exclude the rows manually what should I do to convert the rows that are correct and ignore the ones that raise errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can have pandas ignore the values it can't figure out and just set them to `NaT`. [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

example:

```py
sanitized_dates = pd.to_datetime(dates, errors='coerce')
```

If you desire more specific handling, you may wish to write your own function and use a `Series.apply()` to handle any specific corrections.